# Django load ES6 javascript file

Tags: django, ecmascript-6, django-templates, es6-modules, django-staticfiles

I would like to use the import feature in ES6 in index.html in django.

I do not want to compile to ES5 for browser compatibility. I would like to assume that all the users will have ES6 compatible browsers.

Therefore I do not need a ES6 to ES5 compiler such as Babel: https://github.com/kottenator/django-compressor-toolkit

I simply would like to serve the ES6 Javascript and the browser to compile it if it can.

I tried:

```
<!-- Index.html -->
<script type="module" src="{% static 'app.js' %}"></script>
```

---

```
//app.js
(function(){
  console.log("Hello from App.js");
})();
```

---

```
# settings.py
if DEBUG:
    import mimetypes
    mimetypes.add_type("module", ".js", True)
```

---

The error I get:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

---

**Update 1:** I tried:

```
<script type="module" src="{% static 'app.js' %}"></script>
<script nomodule  src="{% static 'app.js' %}"></script>
<script type="module">import "{% static 'main.mjs' %}";</script>
```

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules

---

**Update 2:** Is it possible NOT to use a precompiler?

[image]

https://github.com/kottenator/django-compressor-toolkit

**Update 3:** I found

https://module-script-tests-sreyfhwvpq.now.sh/mime

[image]
[image]

And this is what I have: 
[image]

**I use Chrome:**
Google Chrome is up to date
Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**Update 4:**
I would like to use

```
<!-- index.html -->
<script type="module"> instead of <script type="text/javascript">
```

because I want to be able to import modules:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<script type="application/javascript" src="{% static 'app.js' %}"></script>

//app.js
import { print } from "{% static 'component.js' %}"
```

currently gives error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

---

**Update 5:**

This is my file structure:

[image: Update 5:]

This is my Index:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<h1>Index</h1>
{% include 'component.html' %}
<script type="module" src="{% static 'app.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

This is my base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Index</title>
    {% load static from staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

This is my app.js:

```
import {A} from "./component.js"
console.log("A" + A)
```

This is my component.js:

```
export const A = 42
```

This is the error I still get:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

This is what I get for content type:

[image]

Comment: The `django-compressor-toolkit` allows you to enable ES6 in Django project. I enable ES6 using this project.

Comment: Yes, but the compressor toolkit is there for converting ES6 to ES5. I should not have to convert it in modern browsers right? I would like to simply run the ES6 html code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally got it working.

This is what I needed to add to the settings.

```
if DEBUG:
    import mimetypes
    mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)
```

The mistake I was making was that I was refreshing but no clearing cache while I was debugging.

If you debug network stuff always make sure to ctrl+F5 when you test.

[image]

If I comment the mimetype:

```
if DEBUG:
    import mimetypes
    #mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)
```

Then I get the error:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

And I see this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I tested on my local environment. It's working fine.
I follow these steps:

1. In `settings.py` add this

   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
   ]
2. In template use this and keep `app.js` in `PROJECT_DIRECTORY/static/` folder.
3. My `app.js` code written from `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benmvp/learning-es6/master/examples/es6/block-scoping.js`

My html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update:**
I create a JS file `test.js` in `static` folder with the following code:

```
export const A = 42
```

I updated my previous `app.js` with the following code:

```
import {A} from "./test.js"

console.log("A" + A)
```

Then in template:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="{% static 'app.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have text/javascript type instead of module that it why it works. Bu you cannot import a module. I want to be able to call import * from 'mymodule.js' inside the app.js

Comment: I got it solved and explained in the answer I gave. I had the right solution all along using mimetypes. But I was not debugging correctly when updating settings.py